# MongoDB + Node: Positional Operator In Combination With Conditional & Equals Operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following document structure:

```js
{
  name: "JohnDoe",
  list: [
    { text: "Text", checked: "2023-01-23" },
    // ...
  ],
}
```

Given a `name` and `text` I can find one document and then update the checked field of the correct array element:

```js
collection.updateOne(
  { name, "list.text": text },
  { $set: { "list.$.checked": "2023-01-24" }}
);
```

Now my question is: Is it possible to calculate the new value based on the current value using the `$cond` and `$eq` operators, and if so, what would be the correct syntax? Specifically, I want to differentiate between the case in which the value is the current date, and the case where it is not.

From my understanding, I have to use an aggregation pipeline in order for this to work. So I tried the following:

```js
collection.updateOne(
  { name, "list.text": text },
  [
    {
      $set: {
        "list.$.checked": {
          $cond: {
            if: { $eq: ["list.$.checked", date()] },
            then: "",
            else: date(),
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
);
```

However, this gets me the error message "Invalid $set :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField.". I don't understand how this query is supposed to look like for it to work.

Comment: That should be possible, have you tried it?

Comment: @Joe I just added my attempt at a solution, which is not working. Maybe you could tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$cond](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) and [$eq](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) are aggregation operators, not update operators.
In order to use those operators in an update, you will need to use the [pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) type of update.
However, inside the pipeline you will not be able to use the `$` positional operator, so you would likely need to [$map](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) the array to set that value.